# cross-similarity between users in python

Tags: python

I have a user group list `UserGroupA=[CustomerA_id1,CustomerA_id2 ....]` containing 1000 users and user group list `UserGroupB=[CustomerB_id1,CustomerB_id2 ...]` containing 10000 users and I have a similarity function defined for any two users from `UserGroupA` and `UserGroupB`
`Similarity(CustomerA_id(k),CustomerB_id(l))` where `k` and `l`  are indices for users in Group A and B.

My objective is to find the most similar 1000 users from Group B to users in GroupA and the way I want to use `CrossSimilarity` to determine that. Is there a more efficient way to do it especially when the size of GroupB increases?

```
  CrossSimilarity = None * [10000]
  for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(1000):
      CrossSimilarity[i] = CrossSimilarity[i] + Similarity(CustomerA_id[k],CustomerB_id[i])
  CrossSimilarity.sort()
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of CustomerA_id[k] or CustomerB_id[l]?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the `Similarity` function and how much time it takes. I expect it will heavily dominate your runtime, but without a runtime profile, it's hard to say. I have some general advice only:

- Have a look at how you calculate `Similarity` and whether you can improve the process by doing everyone from group A, or B in one go rather than starting from scratch.
- There are some micro-optimisations you can do: For example `+=` will be tiny bit faster. Caching `CustomerB_id` in outer loop as well. You can likely squeeze some time out of your similarity function the same way. But I wouldn't expect this time to matter.
- If your code is using pure python and is CPU-heavy, you could try compiling via CPython, or running in Pypy instead of standard Python.

Comment: Caching CustomerB_id would mean just using an iterator in the outer look that keeps the value of CustomerB_id?

Comment: `for i in ...: customer_b = CustomerB_id[i] ; for j in ....: Similarity(..., customer_b)` - but as I said, if you have more than a couple instructions in `Similarity`, it probably won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you are doing is basically a matrix multiplication between the two list (UserGroupA and UserGroupB) a more efficient and fastest way to perform it in memory, could be to use the scikit-sklearn module that provide the function:

```
sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric='euclidean')
```

where obviously X=UserGroupA and Y=UserGroupB and in metric field you can use the default similarity measure of sklearn or pass your own.

It will return a distance matrix D such that  then D_{i, k} is the distance between the ith array from X and the kth array from Y.

Then to find the top 1000 similar user you can simply transform the matrix in a list and sort it.

Maybe is a little more articulated than your solution but should be faster:)